# Can I subscribe in an on_subscribe callback?

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have created a function that returns `on_subscribe` callback to subscribe to multiple topics. However, it didn't work and the callback is not being processed. I did not subscribe in the on_connect callback, is it even necessary?
**This the function created in a class**

```
    def subscriber(self):
        def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
            client.subscribe(self._topic_sub) #topic_sub is an attribute of the class and the topic to 
                                              #subscribe to
        return on_subscribe
    def connection(self):
        def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
            print("Connection to the broker. Result : "+str(rc))

        return on_connect
```

**This is where I am calling the callback**, and it is a part of the code

```
from class_light import Light
from test_class import Mqtt
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
import threading
import time
#from untitled3 import Location
from MongoDB import is_circadian_Light


Broker            = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"
username          = "growthtechnology"
password          = "growthtechnology"
PortaBroker       = 1883
KeepAliveBroker   = 60
client_name       = "Local"

topic_sub = "testtopic/1" 
topic_pub = "testtopic/3"

light = Mqtt(topic_sub)
occupancy_sensor =Mqtt([("testtopic/4", 0), ("testtopic/5", 0)]) 
tunable_light = Light("deviceID")


try:
    print("[STATUS] Inicializando MQTT...")
    #inicializing MQTT:
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect     = light.connection()
    client.on_message     = light.message()
    client.on_publish     = light.publisher()
    client.on_disconnect  = light.disconnection()
    client.on_subscribe   = light.subscriber()
    client.on_subscribe   = occupancy_sensor.subscriber()

    client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)

    def publishing():
        while True:
            msg = light.messages # calling for the variable "messages" to get PUBLISH messages
            #print(msg)
            #time.sleep(3)
            topic = light.topic
            for i, topics in enumerate(topic):
                if topics == "testtopic/4":
                    if msg[i] == "1":
                        if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 :
                            client.publish("testtopic/Bedroom",tunable_light.circadianLight())
                            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `on_subscribe()` is called when ever a call to `client.subscribe()` completes, so you'll end up in the recursive loop...

Comment: I have a class that contains all the necessary callbacks and I will call them in main. Since I cannot call a callback more than one time I decided to put the ```client.subscribe()``` in the on_subscribe callback and not in the  on_connect callback. I didn't find another way to do this because I need the object client to be passed as a parameter. Besides, I have multiple subscriptions so it is not recommended to write ```client.subscribe()``` for each subscription in the main. Sorry but I an new to MQTT is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `on_subscribe` callback twice. As discussed in your last question, you can not do that.

```
client.on_subscribe = light.subscriber()
client.on_subscribe = occupancy_sensor.subscriber()
```

And as I pointed out in the comments, it doesn't make sense to try and subscribe in the callback that is only triggered when a subscription is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `on_subscribe` callback from the function `subscriber()` and I passed as a parameter `client` :

```
def subscriber(self, client):
    client.subscribe(self._topic_sub)
```

then I called the function in main:

```
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect     = Mqtt.connection()
    client.on_message     = light.message()
    client.on_publish     = Mqtt.publisher()
    client.on_disconnect  = Mqtt.disconnection()

    client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)

    light.subscriber(client)
    occupancy_sensor.subscriber(client)
```

And now it works well!